# Dropzone.js - Laravel | 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

I want to upload my images with dropzone.js, I get images on server side, its ok. But When I want to try save, it gives `500 internal server error`.

```
Dropzone.options.mDropzoneTwo = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFiles: 10,
  maxFilesize: 10, // MB
  url: 'images/save' ,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content
   },
  uploadMultiple: true,
  accept: function(file, done) {
          done();
          },
  success: function () {
          console.log()
          }
        };
```

And here is my controller. I'm saving images to public/uploads folder.

```
 $realname = str_slug(pathinfo($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));
 $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $new_name = $realname."-".time().".".$extension;
 $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/'.str_slug($new_name)));
 $image = new Media();
 $image->image = str_slug($new_name);
 $image->image_path = "images/".str_slug($new_name);
 $image->image_alt_name = $realname;
 $image->save();
```

Comment: A 500 response from the server would indicate that your Laravel controller method is raising some kind of error. I'd check your log file `/storage/logs/laravel.log` to see if you find anything there.

Comment: it says =  local.ERROR: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array {"userId":1,"email":"cervantes.ias@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array at /var/www/parti/app/Http/Controllers/MediaController.php:17)

Comment: Does it mean something ? I didin't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments --

It means your application is not getting file object on `$request->file('file')` this, you can get more info by printing `$request` and then you can check for file too weather its being sent from client script or not